# Searching through API in Vuetify autocomplete search is very slow

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using the Vuetify Autocomplete component to search through all stock symbols and company names (117230 in total). When I enter a search term, the browser becomes very laggy for a few seconds. When I tried it with few records (6000), there were no problems. The API is hosted locally for now.

I am assuming this job should be done by the backend? But I'm not sure how. What are my options?

Javascript code in the search component:

```
import Chart from './GChart.vue'
export default {
  name: "Search",
  components: {
    Chart,
  },
  data: () => ({
    symbolsExchangesNames: [],
    isLoading: false,
    model: null,
    search: null
  }),

  computed: {
    items () {
      return this.symbolsExchangesNames
    }
  },

  watch: {
    search (val) {
      console.log(val)
      if (this.items.length > 0) return
      if (this.isLoading) return
      this.isLoading = true
      fetch('http://localhost/API/allSymbolsExchangesNames')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          for(let i of res){
            this.symbolsExchangesNames.push({
              Code: i.Symbol,
              Exchange: i.Exchange,
              Name: i.Name,
              CodeAndName: `${i.Symbol} ${i.Name}`
            })
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
        .finally(() => (this.isLoading = false))
    }
  }
}
```

This is how the data looks like:

```
[{"Symbol": "A", "Exchange": "US", "Name": "Agilent Technologies, Inc"}, {"Symbol": "AA", "Exchange": "US", "Name": "Alcoa Corporation"},...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

117k records takes sometime to be rendered in HTML.

I'd suggest you to use some `debounce` function (in the example below I used [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/#debounce)), to only query your backend when the user stops typing or you could use some real type of input, like pressing enter in the input or submitting the form.

And you should prevent the backend from returning so many records, so yeah, you should filter results in your backend, it's usually used query string on GET requests for this (https://www.google.com/search?q=text%20to%20search)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      query: "",
      data: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // with debounce, 300ms after user stops typing, the callback will be executed
    search: _.debounce(function() {
      // here you should query your backend, something like
      // http://localhost/API/allSymbolsExchangesNames?query=#{this.query}
      this.data = [1,2,3]
    }, 300)

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="query" @keypress="search" />
  {{data}}
</div>
```